# How to set Content-Type Header in Java MicroProfile RestClient during method call

Tags: java, quarkus, content-type, rest-client, microprofile

I am currently using the Java MicroProfile RestClient and have following problem:

- Backend provides an api to receive binary files
- Backend would be happy to receive a Content-Type header containing the Mime-Type of the binary file
- I am not able to set Content-Type per method parameter

I have following code on client-side:

```
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;

@RegisterRestClient
public interface RestClient {
    @POST
    @Path("/api/path/v1")
    Uni<String> createResource(@HeaderParam("Content-Type") String contentType, byte[] body);
}
```

The @HeaderParam("Content-Type") will always be overwritten with "application/json".

If I set the @Consumes Property the Content-Type would always be the same but I want to set it during the method call. (byte[] could contain image, video, text ...)

Has anyone an idea how I could archive this?
May there is a better option instead of using a simple byte[] as body?

Best thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using a `ClientRequestFilter`?

Comment: @geonand have you a suggestion how this could work?I have worked with ClientRequestFilters in the past to overwrite HTTP Headers but in this case I need to set a specific Content-Type per method call. I could add an Header like "ContentType" use this in ClientRequestFilter and set the value afterwards to "Content-Type" Header but this seems to be hacky.

Comment: @geoand have tried, Content-Type will be still overwritten. Have tried is as following:

Comment: '''
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerRequest;

@ Provider
public class MyFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {
    
    @ Inject
    HttpServerRequest httpServerRequest;

    @ Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext)  {
        httpServerRequest.headers().remove("Content-Type");
        httpServerRequest.headers().set("Content-Type", "image/jpg");
    }
}
'''

Comment: If I set an other http header like "sample" it will be added to the request

Comment: @geoand do you have any other idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

i just found the solution for this question.

You need to set annotation `@Consumes(MediaType.MEDIA_TYPE_WILDCARD)`

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MEDIA_TYPE_WILDCARD)
Response post(@Nullable Object bodyRq);
```

then set the Content-Type while register header

```
 var call = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .baseUri(new URI(uri))
            .register(new HeaderAddingFilter(headersRq)) // Content-Type: Application/xml for example
            .build(GenericOperation.class);
```

so then the resteasy-client will sent the `content-type` header following the value set on `headerRq`.

hope this help other who facing same usecase.